# How to make 3 floating divs into 2 floating divs inside a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

I am making an ecommerce website. In fullscreen view, 3 products i.e 3 product tiles i.e 3 divs are shown side by side. Below is the relevant css codes.

```
.single-product{ 
     width: 33%;
     float: left;
     margin: 2px 64px;
     background: white;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
   
} /* For each individual product */

.products-section{
     display:flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-evenly;
     padding-top: 20px;
} /* For the whole product section */
```

When I switch to mobile view, the same 3 products are shown on the screen in smaller product tiles.
Now, I want the page to only display 2 product tiles instead of 3 when the screen is in mobile view. How do i do that in css?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show your markup. put that and your CSS in a demo snippet.

Comment: With a media query

Comment: `floating divs inside a flexbox` -> Makes me cringe... Why do you use the outdated `float hack` if you use a flexbox already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `media` query:

```css
body>div {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body>div>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
}

body>div>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

body>div>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightpink;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  body>div>div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div >
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
```